# what is the use of maven-jaxb2-plugin?

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws

what is the use of maven-jaxb2-plugin? is it used to generate java classes from xsd? what kind of classes does it generates from xsd?

```
maven-jaxb2-plugin
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most common use is in soap based webservices, SOAP webservices exposes WSDL and that defines the schema of the classes being used in webservices

for example:

```
public void sayHello(Person person){}
```

Now client need to make call to it using an instance of `Person` which client will come to know from WSDL and this plugin helps to generate this classes

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it generates POJOs with JAXB annotations from XSDs.